# I want to match the particular id in angular foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to match the `id` and i need to get the description of the particular how can i get this  ??

How can i fix this  ?

```
$scope.getAlbumList = '[{"album_desc":"Test1","id":1,"album_title":"Test","ImageName":"Desert.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Desert.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Desert.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]},{"album_desc":"Test1","id":2,"album_title":"Test1","ImageName":"Koala.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Koala.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Koala.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]},{"album_desc":"Album Title","id":3,"album_title":"Album Title","ImageName":"Tulips.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Tulips.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Tulips.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]},{"album_desc":"fsdfdsfds fsdfds fds fdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfbdsfkdskjfh dskjfh skjdfhdskjhfk sjdhfdskjhfksjdhfkjdsfh sf dfsjfnkjdshf dsjhf ksksfhkjfhds fdshfhkjdsfhdskjhfkj dshf dskjfh skjdhfskjdhfkjdsfhdskjfhkjdsfhsd fkjdshfkjsdhfkj hjshdjfhdskjfhs fdsjhf dskjhfdskjfh dskjfhdskjfhsdkjfhdskjfsdk jdshfkjdsh kjfdshkjfshkjdfshkj fdshkjdskjsh kjds hfkjsd kdshfkjdshfkjsdhfkjdshfkjdshfkjsdkjf fkjdsh fkjshdfkjdshf dskjf","id":4,"album_title":"sdfds","ImageName":"Lighthouse.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Lighthouse.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Lighthouse.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]}]';
$scope.getalbumarray = 'http://localhost/learn/comment/#/album_details/1';

        angular.forEach($scope.getAlbumList, function(item) {
        $scope.albumDescription = item.id;      
        //console.log(item.id);
        //console.log($scope.getalbumarray[$scope.getalbumarray.length - 1]);
        if(item.id == $scope.getalbumarray[$scope.getalbumarray.length - 1]){
            $scope.albumDescription = item.album_desc;
            //console.log('1');
        }else{
            //console.log('2');
            $scope.albumDescription = item.album_desc;
        }
         });

         console.log($scope.albumDescription);
        $scope.showDescrption = $scope.albumDescription;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it will work for you

```
  $scope.getalbumarray = window.location.href.split('/');

        $scope.albumDescr = '';
        var albumId = $scope.getalbumarray[$scope.getalbumarray.length - 1];
        var albums = $scope.getAlbumList.filter(function(item) {

            if(item.id == albumId){             
                $scope.albumDescr += item.album_desc;
            }           
            //return $scope.albumDescription = item.album_desc;;
        })[0];

        $scope.albumDescription = $scope.albumDescr;
        console.log('$scope.albumDescription');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.getAlbumList
```

has become a string since you add

```
$scope.getAlbumList = '[{"album_desc":"Test1", .... ,"pic_id":"d5bd"}]}]';
```

Remove the quotes. And it should look like this:

```
$scope.getAlbumList = [{"album_desc":"Test1", .... ,"pic_id":"d5bd"}]}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$scope.getAlbumList = '[{"album_desc":"Test1","id":1,"album_title":"Test","ImageName":"Desert.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Desert.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Desert.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]},{"album_desc":"Test1","id":2,"album_title":"Test1","ImageName":"Koala.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Koala.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Koala.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]},{"album_desc":"Album Title","id":3,"album_title":"Album Title","ImageName":"Tulips.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Tulips.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Tulips.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]},{"album_desc":"fsdfdsfds fsdfds fds fdsfdsfdsfsdfdsfbdsfkdskjfh dskjfh skjdfhdskjhfk sjdhfdskjhfksjdhfkjdsfh sf dfsjfnkjdshf dsjhf ksksfhkjfhds fdshfhkjdsfhdskjhfkj dshf dskjfh skjdhfskjdhfkjdsfhdskjfhkjdsfhsd fkjdshfkjsdhfkj hjshdjfhdskjfhs fdsjhf dskjhfdskjfh dskjfhdskjfhsdkjfhdskjfsdk jdshfkjdsh kjfdshkjfshkjdfshkj fdshkjdskjsh kjds hfkjsd kdshfkjdshfkjsdhfkjdshfkjdshfkjsdkjf fkjdsh fkjshdfkjdshf dskjf","id":4,"album_title":"sdfds","ImageName":"Lighthouse.jpg","album_pics":[{"media_type":"image/jpeg","last_modified_date":1247549551000,"thumnail_pic_loc":"Lighthouse.jpg","large_pic_loc":"Lighthouse.jpg","filter_type":"image/jpeg","pic_id":"d5bd"}]}]';
$scope.getalbumarray = 'http://localhost/learn/comment/#/album_details/1';

        angular.forEach(JSON.parse($scope.getAlbumList), function(item) {
        $scope.albumDescription = item.id;      
        //console.log(item.id);
        //console.log($scope.getalbumarray[$scope.getalbumarray.length - 1]);
        if(item.id == $scope.getalbumarray[$scope.getalbumarray.length - 1]){
            $scope.albumDescription = item.album_desc;
            //console.log('1');
        }else{
            //console.log('2');
            $scope.albumDescription = item.album_desc;
        }
         });

         console.log($scope.albumDescription);
        $scope.showDescrption = $scope.albumDescription;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not extracting an album id from the URL string, now you are getting the last character of the id always which will break for ids that have more then 2 chars in them.

Try this

```
$scope.getalbumarray = 'http://localhost/learn/comment/#/album_details/1';

var albumId = $scope.getalbumarray.split('/').pop();
var albums = $scope.getAlbumList.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === albumId;
})[0];
```

After that `albums` will be first matched album. I assume that you only need one of them (and there will be only one always or `undefined`) if nothing was found.